# Laravel 8 Quilljs save data to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a Form with three Quilljs Editors. now if I try to save it to my database, I will get nothing. So is there any way to save quilljs Content to DB and how can I load the data from the db to die quilljs editor?

here is a small snippet from my blade File:

```
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="test">Information</label>
                                <div id="test"> </div>
                         </div>
                  </div>
                    ...
          </div>
 </div>
```

My Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request-validate([
            ...
            'test' => 'nullable',
            ...
    
    $input = $request->all();
    ...
    
    Testtable::create($input);

    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'You successfully add a new Product!');
    
}
```

I hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

you can't create table like that

please follow laravel docs
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Comment: Hello @SKIg, I can create a table entry like this. That´s an official form to add on Laravel 8. Here is a Link to that docs from laravel 8: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

But it not a solution for my problem.